# Cannot view table in MySQL Workbench

Tags: xampp, mysql-workbench

Hi guys need some help for MySQL workbench. I'm using a mac and i have installed Xampp and MySQL Workbench. But after creating a database and table I'm not able to view the tables. It's telling me `Tables could not be fetched`. Any idea how can I fix it ?

Below is the screenshot of the table error:
[image]

Comment: Post some prints related to it.

Comment: what you mean by prints related ? example ?

Comment: It seems like the bug hasn't been fixed. I am still having this problem. Even tables shows could not be fecthed. But I can use sql to fetch the tables and views.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that is the same problem as described in this bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96357. When you look in the log file (see Help -> Show Log File) you will see that a specific P_S (performance_schema) table could not be fetched, either because you use a server which doesn't have that table or because you have not the privileges to access P_S.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

In case you're using **docker**, with a **mapped drive** (i.e. your db tables sits on an external drive), updating the image version will not suffice.

Indeed, the DB container version will be upgraded, but the the DB schemas won't.

To do that, connect to your container via docker exec:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh
```

Now run `mysql_upgrade` command

E.g. I updated my mariadb version:

```
#  mysql_upgrade -u XXX -p XXX
Enter password:
Major version upgrade detected from 10.2.44-MariaDB to 10.6.14-MariaDB. Check required!
Phase 1/7: Checking and upgrading mysql database
Processing databases
mysql
mysql.column_stats                                 OK
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.gtid_slave_pos                               OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
...
...
...
Phase 7/7: Running 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES'
OK
```